# Linq join and group by

Tags: linq, group-by

I am trying to write the following PLSQL query in linq, but am coming a little unstuck on the group by:

```
    select 
sub.EmpID,
Min(sub.Stage1) Stage1,
Min(sub.Stage2) Stage2,
Min(sub.Stage3) Stage3,
Min(sub.Prob1) Prob1,
Min(sub.Prob2) Prob2


from

(select 
det.det_numbera EmpID,
case when apr.apr_performa = '1'
  then max(apr.apr_datec)
  else null
end Stage1,
case when apr.apr_performa = '2'
  then max(apr.apr_datec)
  else null
end Stage2,
case when apr.apr_performa = '3'
  then max(apr.apr_datec)
  else null
end Stage3,
case when apr.apr_performa = '5'
  then max(apr.apr_datec)
  else null
end Prob1,
case when apr.apr_performa = '6'
  then max(apr.apr_datec)
  else null
end Prob2

from emdet det

left outer join emapr apr
on det.det_numbera = apr.det_numbera

group by det.det_numbera, apr.apr_performa) sub

group by sub.Empid
```

I have managed to partially do the sub query but came unstuck on the grouping before I could get the outer query working:

```
        public List<ComplianceDetails> MyComplianceDetails(List<JobDetail> staff, List<Compliance> compliance)
    {
        List<ComplianceDetails> compdet =
            (from s in staff
             join c in compliance on s.EmpID equals c.EmpId into staffcomp
             from sc in staffcomp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             group s by new { s.EmpID, sc.Stage } into grp


             select new ComplianceDetails(
                 s.EmpID,
                 s.Position,
                 s.Department,
                 s.Division,
                 s.Contract,
                 s.ContService,
                 s.Probation,
                 s.Sessional,
                 s.Teaching,
                 sc.Stage == "1" ? staffcomp.Max(a => a.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null,
                 sc.Stage == "2" ? staffcomp.Max(a => a.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null,
                 sc.Stage == "3" ? staffcomp.Max(a => a.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null,
                 sc.Stage == "5" ? staffcomp.Max(a => a.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null,
                 sc.Stage == "6" ? staffcomp.Max(a => a.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null
               )
            ).ToList();
        return compdet;
    }
```

EDIT//

Thanks for the help, you guided me very close to the solution this seems to work as expected:

```
        public List<ComplianceDetails> MyComplianceDetails(List<JobDetail> staff, List<Compliance> compliance)
    {
        string[] tQuals = new string[] { "21", "22", "23", "24" };

        var compdet =
            (from det in staff
         join apr in compliance on det.EmpID equals apr.EmpId
             into JoinedList
         from apr in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()

         group new { det, apr } by 
               new 
               { 
                   det.EmpID, 
                   Stage = apr == null ? "" : apr.Stage

               } into GroupedList

         select GroupedList.Select(u => new
            {
                    EmpID = u.det.EmpID,
                    FullName = u.det.FullName,
                    Position = u.det.Position,
                    Department = u.det.Department,
                    Division = u.det.Division,
                    Contract = u.det.Contract,
                    ContService = u.det.ContService,
                    Probation = u.det.Probation,
                    Sessional = u.det.Sessional,
                    Teaching = u.det.Teaching,
                    Stage1 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.Stage == "1" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null),
                    Stage2 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.Stage == "2" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null),
                    Stage3 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.Stage == "3" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null),
                    Prob1 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.Stage == "5" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null),
                    Prob2 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.Stage == "6" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null),
                    EduType = u.apr == null ? string.Empty : (tQuals.Contains(u.apr.Stage) ? u.apr.StageDesc : string.Empty),
                    EduDate = u.apr == null ? null : (tQuals.Contains(u.apr.Stage) ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr.LastDate) : (DateTime?)null)
                })
            )
            .SelectMany(u => u)
            .GroupBy(u => u.EmpID)
            .Select(u => new ComplianceDetails
            (
                u.Key,
                u.First().FullName,
                u.First().Position,
                u.First().Department,
                u.First().Division,
                u.First().Contract,
                u.First().ContService,
                u.First().Probation,
                u.First().Sessional,
                u.First().Teaching,
                u.Where(t => t.Stage1 == u.Max(T => T.Stage1)).Select(g => g.Stage1).FirstOrDefault(),
                u.Where(t => t.Stage2 == u.Max(T => T.Stage2)).Select(g => g.Stage2).FirstOrDefault(),
                u.Where(t => t.Stage3 == u.Max(T => T.Stage3)).Select(g => g.Stage3).FirstOrDefault(),
                u.Where(t => t.Prob1 == u.Max(T => T.Prob1)).Select(g => g.Prob1).FirstOrDefault(),
                u.Where(t => t.Prob2 == u.Max(T => T.Prob2)).Select(g => g.Prob2).FirstOrDefault(),
                u.Where(t => t.EduDate == u.Max(T => T.EduDate)).Select(g => g.EduType).FirstOrDefault(),
                u.Where(t => t.EduDate == u.Max(T => T.EduDate)).Select(g => g.EduDate).FirstOrDefault()
            ))
            .ToList();

        return compdet;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is equivalent `linq` of your `tsql`, check this:

```
var query = (from det in emdet
             join apr in emapr on det.det_numbera equals apr.det_numbera 
                 into JoinedList
             from apr in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()

             group new { det, apr } by 
                   new 
                   { 
                       det.det_numbera, 
                       apr_performa = apr == null ? "" : apr.apr.apr_performa 

                   } into GroupedList

             select GroupedList.Select(u => new
                {
                    EmpID = u.det.det_numbera,
                    Stage1 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.apr_performa == "1" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr_datec) : null),
                    Stage2 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.apr_performa == "2" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr_datec) : null),
                    Stage3 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.apr_performa == "3" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr_datec) : null),
                    Prob1 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.apr_performa == "5" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr_datec) : null),
                    Prob2 = u.apr == null ? null : (u.apr.apr_performa == "6" ? GroupedList.Max(t => t.apr_datec) : null)
                })
            )
            .SelectMany(u => u)
            .GroupBy(u => u.EmpID)
            .Select(u => new 
            {
                EmpID = u.Key,
                Stage1 = u.Where(t => t.Stage1 != null).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(t => t.Stage1),
                Stage2 = u.Where(t => t.Stage2 != null).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(t => t.Stage2),
                Stage3 = u.Where(t => t.Stage3 != null).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(t => t.Stage3),
                Prob1 = u.Where(t => t.Prob1 != null).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(t => t.Prob1),
                Prob2 = u.Where(t => t.Prob2 != null).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(t => t.Prob2)
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. I have had a try with your example but I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the line new { det.det_numbera, apr.apr_performa }. I can see that the det_numbera or "EmpId" has a value, but it is possible that an employee has no stages, hence I guess stage would be null.

Comment: i edited the first `GroupBy`, check that again, let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I seem to be a little further now and it gets to the second select but gets another "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on  t.Stage1 from the line: Stage1 = u.Where(t => t.Stage1 != null).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(t => t.Stage1), It seems as if t is null? And ideas? Cheers Andy

Comment: oh !!!!!, the `t` cant be null, try to put `t != null` in `where` statements on second select, and see the result, this may solve your `null` reference, add this: `Where(t => t != null && t.Stage1 != null)`

Comment: Hi, just tried with the t != null and I get the same error on the same `.Min(t => t.Stage1)` from the line in the second select: `Stage1 = u.Where(t => t != null && t.Stage1 != null).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(t => t.Stage1)`

Comment: are u sure, this line causing exception ?? what about this: `Stage1 = u == null ? defaul(**) : u.Where(t => t != null && t.Stage1 != null).Select(t => t.Stage1).DefaultIfEmpty().Min()`, i think this should be solve that, if it's solve your problem, (replace '**' with type of `stage1`), tell me to correct my post

Comment: Hi Thanks I swapped the last select around a little to this and it seems to work: `u.Where(t => t.Stage1 == u.Max(T => T.Stage1)).Select(g => g.Stage1).FirstOrDefault(),`

Comment: i dont have any idea, about what you have written, but if you write what i told at prev comment, it will be ok probably